# jQuery Daterange Picker only showing current and future dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, date-range

I need to display dates in the past. I am currently displaying today's date and dates in the future. Dates in the past are currently non-selectable. I need to know how to make them selectable.

Currently, this code shows 3 months in the past, but it only allows the user to select today's date or dates in the future. I need the date picker range to allow users to select dates from the past as well.

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  numberOfMonths: [3, 1],
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());

    // console.log(moment.utc(date1).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    // console.log(moment.utc(date2).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

    // instantiate array to hold all dates selected in date range
    var getDaysArray = function(s, e) {
      for (var a = [], d = new Date(s); d <= e; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        a.push(new Date(d));
      }
      return a;
    };

    // daylist contains all dates between both dates selected
    var daylist = getDaysArray(date1, date2);

    daylist.map((v) => v.toISOString().slice(0, 10)).join("")
    // console.log(daylist);

    // iterate over dates selected to populate table data for days selected
    for (var i = 0; i < daylist.length; i++) {
      // console.log(daylist[i]);
      // console.log(moment.utc(daylist[i]).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    }

    return [
      true,
      date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""
    ];
  },
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
    var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

    if (!date1 || date2) {
      $("#input1").val(dateText);
      $("#input2").val("");
      $(this).datepicker();
    } else if (selectedDate < date1) {
      $("#input2").val($("#input1").val());
      $("#input1").val(dateText);
      $(this).datepicker();
    } else {
      $("#input2").val(dateText);
      $(this).datepicker();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Change or remove `minDate: 0`. jQueryUI has very comprehensive documentation. If you're ever unsure about a setting I'd suggest checking there: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this worked thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply change or remove minDate: 0. This will display dates from the present, past, and future allowing the user to select them.